# Get telephone number in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Is there a way to get a telephone number of the store in any place of template?
In blockcontact.tpl we have:

```
{if $telnumber != ''}
        <p class="tel">
            <span class="label">{l s='Phone:' mod='blockcontact'}</span>{$telnumber|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
        </p>
    {/if}
```

Can I take that $telnumber out of hooks at top of my page in header.tpl?

Comment: This module already render tpl in header. See [Image](http://nimb.ws/RG6wur)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In blockcontact.tpl you have the {$telnumber} because is assigned from the controller of this template, in this case blockcontact.php file.

Line +-185:

```
$smarty->assign(array(

            'telnumber' => Configuration::get('BLOCKCONTACT_TELNUMBER'),
            ...
```

Here you can see the way that is assigned the $telnumber variable.

---

Then, if you want to use this in any place, or any template, first you need to go to the Controller of the template that you need and, in the correct function  use the second way that answered **@sarcom**:

> if it's a **module** probably in the function of the hook that's the **template hooked**, and if it's a **core controller** in the **initContent()**
>   function.

And then you can use the **{$telnumber}** in the template.

If you need to edit a core controller, the best way is to use the **override** feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can place this code in your themes any tpl file; it works!!!

```
{if Configuration::get('BLOCKCONTACT_TELNUMBER') != ''}
    <span>{Configuration::get('BLOCKCONTACT_TELNUMBER')}</span>
{/if}
```

Make sure you have added telephone number in admin panel in module named "**Contact block**"

Comment: My friend, it's the 'same' tip that I have already said :) but he say that don't work...

Comment: Yeah! but with some addition like checking in module in telephone added....

Answer (score 0):

It's a dirty way, but works:

```
{Configuration::get('BLOCKCONTACT_TELNUMBER')}
// This snippet can be used in every .tpl
```

The other way is to override or edit the module, and add in `hookDisplayHeader` method this snippet:

```
$this->context->smarty->assign(array(
    'telnumber' => Configuration::get('BLOCKCONTACT_TELNUMBER')
));
```

Comment: Are you disabled the cache? Ensure that the `BLOCKCONTACT_TELNUMBER` is populated, and trust me, that snippet works at 100% :)

Comment: Prestashop 1.6.1.4, no cache, BLOCKCONTACT_TELNUMBER not empty (displays telephone number in footer hook) - displays nothing.

Comment: Do you have a link? I just make a test in a my prestashop test shop: http://ps1604.tanzows.it/it/ (v1.6.0.4)